# Duplicate results in Result Source, CSP, Search

Tags: 2013, search-results, cross-site-publishing, cswp

We have a cross-site publishing environment set up. On the authoring side we have our **ContentLibrary** which contains custom docset content types.

On the publishing/user facing side, we've connected the catalog and set up the category and item pages and have URL rewriting working.

However when we make a change to the name (or other metadata) associated with an item on the author side we start getting duplicate results on the user side. In the Result Source and then in the CSWP and user-initiated search results page -- both of which use the Result Source as the basis for their information.

So for example, if I change the name of an entry with an ID of 788 from

```
This is the Original name
This is the New name
```

After the item is index it will show up as two items with different names but both leading to

```
/example.com/usersite/Pages/Details.aspx?ID=788
```

And in our content search web parts I will get two instances of the item template.

I found [this page](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/Change-settings-for-the-Search-Results-Web-Part-40ff85b3-bc5e-4230-b1dd-f088188e487e) about setting the trim duplicates on the search results page, but it is already set and isn't working. And that would only fix it for the results page and not the CSWP.

There is also found several pages that talk about going into the query builder for the cswp and going to the settings tab. But on my settings tab there is no trim duplicates choice.

It does seem that after a day or so the old results do go away, but I'm not sure.
Any idea how to get the old results out of the search when the new results come in?

Comment: What's your full and incremental crawl schedule?

Comment: Do you have continuous crawling enabled?